# iOS Linked in how to get full profile and connection at same request?

Tags: ios, oauth, linkedin-api

Can we get full profile details and user connections at same time through linked in. Oauth Api

I am getting user profile details and user connections details in separate request.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,email-address,location,id)"];
```

but when i get connections details it do not provide users profile info, vise versa.
for request parameter i used below code

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope" value:@"r_fullprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network"];
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];
[request setParameters:params];

    OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope"   value:@"r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network"];
 [request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];
```

Many thanks in advance.
need help

Comment: what solution did u find on this ?

Comment: @JgdGuy not get it in one request, used two different requests,one for profile and one for connections.

Comment: @Gagan: Can share code with us for how to get full profile data of login User.